# ggplot2 set text at a fixed position common to all categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to customize a violinplot by displaying the median above each bar. 
However, different bars have different values and by using "vjust", "position_dodge/identity" the final location will be calculated starting from the median value itself.

I want instead to have all texts at the same coordinates (like at y = 100, x = my bar).
Here's the code I wrote so far. Violin Plot is plotted using a function of the variancePartition package, but it uses ggplot2 interface, while n_fun is a function which return the median of each category.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(variancePartition)

n_fun <- function(x){
          return(data.frame(y = median(x), label = scales::percent(median(x/100))))
        }    

        plotVarPart(varPart) +
              theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=12), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
              stat_summary(fun.data = n_fun, geom = "text", fontface = "bold", vjust = 1.5, size = 7)
```

[image]

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `y = Inf` instead of `y = median(x)` within `n_fun` and adjust hight with `vjust`

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks!